# Extracting Data from nested divs in HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to export the prices of items of a website with VBA.

This is the page I want to extract the price from:
https://skinport.com/de/item/operation-bravo-case/

The price is in a nested div called ItemPage-Value.

```vb
Sub Update_Price()

Dim MyValue()
Dim Webpage As String
    Webpage = Worksheets(2).Cells(2, 5).Value 'Webpage is loaded from Cell of Excel sheet

Dim content As Object    
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set html = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    .Open "GET", Webpage, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set content = html.querySelectorAll(".ItemPage-value .Tooltip-link")
MyValue(1) = content.Item(1).innerText
Worksheets(2).Cells(2, 12).Value = MyValue 'Write Price in Cell

End Sub
```

The querySelectorAll function does not work as intended.

Comment: To add to this: I succesfully managed to extract the price from another webpage. My problem here seems to be specifically, that the source code is not complete when extracted. I can only extract the source code which i can show with "show sourcecode" in Chrome, but not the Elements i can see when I "inspect" the webpage with Chrome. How do i access those elements?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, it is an explanation of where to find the price and why it is hard to read.

As you have already noticed, the html file downloaded directly from the web server does not contain the information you would like to read. In fact, the downloaded file is only 1.22 kB in size and looks exactly the same for other pages of the website. (I tryed it ;-) )It is merely the basic structure of the displayed pages. With the following VBA code, the html code of the retrieved pages is saved on a drive. I have chosen drive E:, for your computer you may have to adapt it:

The html code for the url you specified:
https://skinport.com/de/item/operation-bravo-case/

```
Sub SkinportSpecificItem()

  Dim url As String
  Dim doc As Object
  
  Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")
  
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    url = "https://skinport.com/de/item/operation-bravo-case/"
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .Send
    
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Close
      Open "E:\GetPrice.html" For Output As #1
      Print #1, .responseText
      Close
    Else
      MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

The html code for the search results of the page when operation bravo is entered as the search term:
https://skinport.com/de/market?search=operation+bravo

```
Sub SkinportSearch()

  Dim url As String
  Dim doc As Object
  
  Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")
  
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    url = "https://skinport.com/de/market?search=operation+bravo"
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .Send
    
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Close
      Open "E:\GetPrice.html" For Output As #1
      Print #1, .responseText
      Close
    Else
      MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

It is the same basic structure. There is nothing in it, it is an empty page. The content is first generated locally by a JavaScript, in the browser on your own computer. Is that magic? No, of course not. When a website is called up in the browser, not only one file is downloaded, which is then displayed in the browser, but there are several files, often even many.

For example, each image displayed is a separate file. Almost every page also uses scripts, i.e. a piece of software that is executed locally in the browser. This software is programmed in JavaScript (JS). Furthermore, the appearance of a website, i.e. the design, is determined by Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). CSS is also often made available in separate files. In addition to these core components of a web page, fonts, other html files and a few other things are also retrieved from the web server.

The web page you mentioned is neatly programmed. It distinguishes between data, representation and algorithms. It is a design pattern. This is called MVC (Model, View, Controller).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller (english)
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller (german)

To come back to the topic. What you are looking for is in a JSON (Java Script Object Notation).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON (english)
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation (german)

Of course, every file that is downloaded from the web server has its own url. The url for the JSON in question is
https://skinport.com/api/item?appid=730&url=operation-bravo-case.

There are two problems with this. First, if you try to call the url, there is an "Acsess Denied" error. So the file cannot be retrieved easily. The second problem is, there is an "appID" 730 that is needed to retrieve the file in order to map the url correctly in the first place.

I didn't pursue the issue because of the 730, because it's hard to get to. I assume the "Acsess Denied" error can be circumvented by intercepting the set cookie and resending it for the query. That alone can no longer be done with xhr, but (as far as I know) only via WinHTTP. It's the same in the end. But as I said, I see the problem mainly in the required ItemID.

I first thought the ID referred to the game. For gloves, which I took from the search, that's also true. But for any weapon, the ID suddenly turns out to be 430, which is a completely different number, and I don't have the time to work out whether there is a way to get this number. As I said, without it, you can't get the JSON you need and I haven't even tried out whether it can be downloaded with the cookie.

I hope this at least explains where the problem lies, or that web scraping is sometimes a tough discipline. Probably "the other website" is the better source.

Comment: Thank you very much, this explanation helped a lot for understanding the problem and the structure of websites, that load JSON files with scripts. At the part with the error circumvention with cookies, my brain told me to stop reading. I am just not that deep into any advanced techniques. Actually I found out, that there is a API provided by SkinPort to their users to access the database of skinport.com. I am trying to get the prices from the API now.